# how to read last two line of values and assign values to previous line from log file using power shell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have log text file (solution.log). How to read last two line of values and how to assign each value to previous line each word like critical =0 ,high=0,medium=0 and informational=0
Please assist on this.

## solution.log

critical High Medium Low Informational

0        0    0      0       0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the last line you could use this:

```
Get-Content solution.log -tail 1
```